# Flutter use context in super

Tags: flutter

I have the following widget

```
class MyContainer extends Container {
  MyContainer ({
      required String text, 
      Key? key,
  }) : super(
      height: 51,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button?.copyWith(color: UIColors.greyText),
        ),
      ),
      key: key,
  );
}
```

Now the keen eyed might have noticed that this line `style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button?.copyWith(color: UIColors.greyText),` will not work, because we are missing the BuildContext.

My issue is that, as you can see, it's a very simple widget and I would hate it if I had to make it a StatelessWidget just because I want to use `Theme.of(context)`.

Is there any way to make my idea work or will I have to resort to StatelessWidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the [Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) class is for! The builder class lets you access BuildContext without having to write another widget with a build method to access the context.

```
class MyContainer extends Container {
  MyContainer ({
    required String text,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(
    height: 51,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      color: Colors.grey,
    ),
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button?.copyWith(color: UIColors.greyText),
          ),
        );
      }
    ),
    key: key,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass BuildContext as a parameter and name the constructor same as the class name.

```
class MyContainer extends Container {
  MyContainer({
    required BuildContext context,
      required String text, 
      Key? key,
  }) : super(
      height: 51,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button?.copyWith(color: UIColors.greyText),
        ),
      ),
      key: key,
  );
}
```

Comment: The name missmatch slipped my eyes when making changes to make it more neutral for SO, thanks. 

So it seems it's either passing context or making it a StatelessWidget I guess, don't know which one I dislike more.

Comment: It is just passing the context into the class, Not making it a stateless. Please verify the answer whether if it is working for you.